# Sorting LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> by counting the occurrences in ArrayList<String> problem

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have:

```
ArrayList<String> miss;
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map;
```

How can i sort "maps" by counting the occurrences in "miss"? For example:

1. miss => [3, 7]
2. maps => {1=[0, **3**, 6], 4=[2, **3**, 4], 6=[0, **3**, **7**], 11=[1, **3**, 6], 17=[2, 6, 11]}

And i want to get:

maps => {6=[0, 3, 7], 1=[0, 3, 6], 4=[2, 3, 4], 11=[1, 3, 6], 17=[2, 6, 11]}

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution is based on using Stream API

1. Count the frequencies of elements from `miss` in each list value of `maps` and collect the frequency into some object (e.g. a list)
2. Sort the new object by the frequency in the reverse order and then by the key of initial map (*note: the key may need to be converted into int to provide the expected output: 1, 4, 11;  comparing the keys as String returns the order 1, 11, 4*)
3. Build the resulting map using `Collectors.toMap` with `LinkedHashMap::new` supplier

```java
List<String> miss = List.of("3", "7");
Map<String, List<String>> maps = Map.of(
     "1", List.of("0", "3", "6"),
     "4", List.of("2", "3", "4"),
     "6", List.of("0", "3", "7"),
    "11", List.of("1", "3", "6"),
    "17", List.of("2", "6", "11")
);

Map<String, List<String>> sorted = maps.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e, 
        e.getValue().stream()
            .mapToInt(i -> (int) miss.stream().filter(i::equals).count())
            .sum()
    ))
    .sorted(Comparator
        .<List>comparingInt(ee -> (int) ee.get(1)).reversed()
        .thenComparingInt(ee -> Integer.parseInt(((Map.Entry<String, List<String>>) ee.get(0)).getKey()))
    )
    .map(ee -> (Map.Entry<String, List<String>>) ee.get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (v1, v2) -> v1,
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));

System.out.println(sorted);
```

Output:

```
{6=[0, 3, 7], 1=[0, 3, 6], 4=[2, 3, 4], 11=[1, 3, 6], 17=[2, 6, 11]}
```